# GitHub dependency in Apache Maven project

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project on github.com:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-github-library</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  ...
</project>
```

Now I want to add my-github-library as a dependency to another my-local-application project:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-local-application</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-github-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

This of course doesn't work because GitHub is not a Maven repository.

**How can I add an additional Maven repository to the project pom file ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request open source hosting for your Github project's artifacts from the [Sonatype OSS team](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide). Then you will have to set up your project to be able to deploy to their repository (using `<distributionManagement/>` in your `pom.xml` and `<servers/>` in your `settings.xml`). Once you have deployed the artifact you're depending on, you can make your other project depend on it via a `<dependency/>` and defining a `<repository>` in your `<repositories/>` section pointing to your repo at Sonatype.